# Тип сказуемого "состоит"

Tags: синтаксис, тип-сказуемого

Скажите, пожалуйста, такой глагол, как "состоит из..." (например, из трех частей), будет являться составным именным сказуемым или все же это простое глагольное сказуемое, состоящее из одного слова "состоит"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Скажите, пожалуйста, такой глагол, как "состоит из..." <...>, будет являться составным именным сказуемым или все же
>   это простое глагольное сказуемое, состоящее из одного слова "состоит"?

**Часть составного именного сказуемого**.

Вот как на аналогичный вопрос отвечали Розенталь и Добромыслов (*Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания: пособие для учителей*. М., 1958):

> Предложение *Семья состоит из трех человек* является
>   нераспространенным: сказуемое выражено в нем сочетанием ***состоит из
>   трех человек***. Глагол ***состоит*** не выступает как знаменательный,
>   а выполняет функцию связки; ср.: *Книга **состоит из ряда очерков**;
>   Единственное развлечение мое **состояло в наездничестве*** (Пушкин).

Comment: Что-то мне не нравятся эти примеры. Прежде всего, они все разные. Пожалуй, только в  примере (3)  "состояло" можно приравнять к связке было. Книга состоит из  ряда очерков?  А вот детям объясняют, что книга состоит из обложки, титульного листа и т.д.  Семья состоит из трех человек? Семья имеет в своем составе, а дальше перечисляем всех домочадцев. Длинное  получается сказуемое...

Comment: _Sharon: Длинное получается сказуемое..._ === Бывает и длиннее. См. у Пушкина: _Она была нетороплива,
Не холодна, не говорлива,
Без взора наглого для всех,
Без притязаний на успех,
Без этих маленьких ужимок,
Без подражательных затей..._

Comment: slava, я против Пушкина не возражаю, там связка присутствует. А у глагола состоять "сильное управление", то есть он лексически не выражен без дополнения. Но это не повод для того,чтобы включать это дополнение в сказуемое. Я классиков очень уважаю, но с 1958 года взгляды могли измениться.

Comment: _Sharon: ...с 1958 года взгляды могли измениться._ === Могли, но... Если Вам такие изменения по поводу разбираемого предложения известны — поделитесь, пожалуйста!

Comment: К составным именным сказуемым в настоящее время предъявляются довольно строгие требования, и это касается связок. Их три вида: связка БЫТЬ, полузнаменательные связки стать, являться и т.д. знаменательные связки со значением движения и положения. Всё, что не укладывается в эти рамки, вызывает сомнения в том, что это именное сказуемое. Возможно, такой подход является новым.

Comment: _Sharon: К составным именным сказуемым в настоящее время предъявляются довольно строгие требования, и это касается связок. Их три вида: связка БЫТЬ, полузнаменательные связки стать, являться **и т.д.** знаменательные связки со значением движения и положения. Всё, что не укладывается в эти рамки, вызывает сомнения в том, что это именное сказуемое. Возможно, такой подход является новым._ === Нет, такой подход не нов. И ещё: Sharon, обратите внимание на "и т.д." в Вашем перечне. По-моему, очень трудно "не уложиться в рамки" при наличии в перечне помет типа _и т.д., и др._ и им подобных...

Comment: Вот интересная статья. https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/znachenie-i-upotreblenie-glagola-sostoyat/viewer

Comment: Я перечисляю полузнаменательные связки: являться, делаться, стать, становиться, казаться, оказаться, показаться, считаться, слыть, называться, оставаться, получаться, выходить. И общая характеристика: НАЛИЧИЕ, СТАНОВЛЕНИЕ, ПРОЯВЛЕНИЕ, ОБНАРУЖЕНИЕ ПРИЗНАКА.

Answer (score 2):

***Ответ Граммы.ру***

Вопрос о наборе связок в русском языке является спорным, поскольку, во-первых, у лингвистов отсутствует единство в понимании границ составного именного сказуемого, частью которого выступает связочный глагол, а во-вторых, неясны критерии (лексические, грамматические и пр.), на основании которых должны выделяться связочные глаголы и отграничиваться от остальных, несвязочных глаголов.
В частности, дискуссионным является вопрос о том, должна ли учитываться при признании за глаголом статуса связочного форма присвязочного члена (именной части). Например, по мнению А.А. Потебни, связочным глаголом может считаться только тот глагол, который способен присоединять к себе в составе присвязочной части существительное или прилагательное в Им. п.
Ответ на Ваш вопрос связан с решением именно этого вопроса: если считать связочными глаголами только те из них, которые способны присоединять к себе Им. и/или Тв. предикативный, то глагол состоять (из) не является полноценной связкой, хотя по своей семантике и примыкает к связкам. Если критерий формы именной части не учитывать, то состоять (из) — это связка. П.А.Лекант предлагает делить связочные глаголы на специализированные и неспециализированные, относя к числу последних те глаголы, которые имеют связочное значение, но не способны присоединять к себе Им. и/или Тв. предикативный. Глагол состоять (из) он относит на этом основании к неспециализированным связкам.

С уважением
GRAMMA.RU

Comment: Спасибо, Серж, за информацию. Правда, у меня  сомнения так и не кончились. Возможно, попробую задать вопрос на нашем форуме, отметив некоторые особенности  глагола состоять (из).

Comment: @Sharon, а вы читали статью по ссылке? Кстати, сотрудник Граммы.ру ответивший на вопрос, - д.ф.н. Его докторская была посвящена как- раз теме связок в русском языке.

Comment: Серж, только просмотрела бегло, но теперь хочу прочитать внимательно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

А на каких основаниях вы ходите включать именную группу "из чего-то там" в сказуемое? Это неправильно.

> Сочинение состоит из трех частей: введения, ответ на вопрос, заключение.

Сочинение – подлежащее. Состоит — сказуемое.

Состоит *из чего?* из частей. (Дополнение.) Из частей *скольких?* трех. (Определение.)

Comment: Лучше я за вас проголосую